# On Form_Open() check links to backend data

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm using a template database that I found somewhere on the internet quite a while ago.  I really wish I remember where I found it so I could at least give the author credit for the routines and back-up ideas, but I haven't had any luck thus far.

I am having an issue with the back-end check on loading the database.  Here is the code I'm using:

```
Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)

    On Error GoTo Err_Handler

    Const conFILENOTFOUND As Integer = 3024
    Const conPATHNOTFOUND As Integer = 3044
    Dim dbs As DAO.Database, rst As DAO.Recordset, tdf As DAO.TableDef
    Dim strTable As String, strConnect As String

    Set dbs = CurrentDb

    ' mimimize database window/navigation pane
'    DoCmd.SelectObject acForm, Me.Name, True
'    DoCmd.Minimize

' test validity of links to back end and open
' form to refersh links if not valid
CheckLinks:
    For Each tdf In dbs.TableDefs
        If Len(tdf.Connect) > 0 Then
            If tdf.Connect <> strConnect Then
                strTable = tdf.Name
                Set rst = dbs.OpenRecordset(strTable)
                strConnect = tdf.Connect
            End If
        End If
    Next tdf

Exit_Here:
    Set rst = Nothing
    Set tdf = Nothing
    Set dbs = Nothing
    Exit Sub

Err_Handler:
    If Err.Number = conFILENOTFOUND Or Err.Number = conPATHNOTFOUND Then
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmUpdate_Links", _
            WindowMode:=acDialog, _
            OpenArgs:="ForceQuit"

        Resume CheckLinks
    Else
        MsgBox Err.Description & " (" & Err.Number & ")"
        Resume Exit_Here
    End If

End Sub
```

The problem lies in the fact that the form isn't firing back at me saying the back-end is wrong (well, to be honest it IS doing this...) and opening `frmUpdate_Links` to update the backend links.  I'm thinking the `conFILENOTFOUND` and/or `conPATHNOTFOUND` error checks are incorrect.  I'm currently working with a database that doesn't have any entries in the two tables it uses to check whether the back-end exists or not.  Those tables are `BackEndLocation` and `FileLocations`.  It's supposed to open `frmUpdate_Links` when there is no entry in these two tables.  Instead I get the typical error that occurs when a database cannot find it's back-end.

There are two modules associated with this routine.  Here is their code:
***First one is `BrowseForFileClass` which is a Class Module -***

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
'  There are default values for the dialog box title and the list of file types
'  in the 'file filter' section of the dialog box.  The calling VBA code can
'  use the following Properties and Methods of this class.
'
'       Properties:
'           DialogTitle -- the text that is displayed as the title of the
'                          dialog box.  The default is "Browse For a File".
'           AdditionalTypes -- one or more additional file types to be added as
'                              one item in the dialog box's file filter list,
'                              formatted like this sample:
'                                   "My Files (*.mf1;*.mf2) | *.mf1;*.mf2 | Your Files (*.yf1;*.yf2) *.yf1;*.yf2"
'                              The following file types are in the built-in list:
'                                   "All Files (*.*)"
'                                   "Text Files (*.txt;*.prn;*.csv)"
'                                   "Word Documents (*.doc)"
'                                   "Word Templates (*.dot)"
'                                   "Rich Text Files (*.rtf)"
'                                   "Excel Files (*.xls)"
'                                   "Databases (*.mdb)"
'                                   "HTML Documents (*.html;*.htm)"
'           DefaultType -- the item in the dialog's file filter list that will be
'                          active when the dialog box is activated.  If the
'                          AdditionalTypes property is not used, the default
'                          is "All files (*.*)".  If the AdditionalTypes property
'                          is used, this property cannot be used and the file type
'                          specified in the AdditionalTypes property will be active
'                          when the dialog box is activated.  To set this property,
'                          specify a string that will match with the desired type,
'                          such as "*.doc" or "HTML".
'           InitialFile -- the file name that is to be displayed in the File Name
'                          field in the dialog box when it is activated.  The
'                          default is to leave the File Name field blank.
'           InitialDir -- the directory/folder which should be active when the
'                         dialog box is activated.  The default is the current
'                         directory.
'
'       Methods:
'           GetFileSpec() -- this function activates the dialog box and then returns
'                            the full path and filename of the file that the User
'                            has selected.  If the User clicks Cancel, a zero
'                            length string is returned.
'


Private Type OPENFILENAME
    lStructSize As Long
    hwndOwner As Long
    hInstance As Long
    lpstrFilter As String
    lpstrCustomFilter As Long
    nMaxCustrFilter As Long
    nFilterIndex As Long
    lpstrFile As String
    nMaxFile As Long
    lpstrFileTitle As String
    nMaxFileTitle As Long
    lpstrInitialDir As String
    lpstrTitle As String
    Flags As Long
    nFileOffset As Integer
    nFileExtension As Integer
    lpstrDefExt As String
    lCustrData As Long
    lpfnHook As Long
    lpTemplateName As Long
End Type

Private Declare Function GetOpenFileName Lib "comdlg32.dll" Alias _
    "GetOpenFileNameA" (pOpenfilename As OPENFILENAME) As Boolean

Private strDialogTitle As String
Private intDefaultType As Integer
Private strNewTypes As String
Private strInitialFile As String
Private strInitialDir As String
Private strFilter As String
Private strFltrLst As String
Private strFltrCnt As String
'   This 'Method' routine displays the Open dialog box for the user to
'   locate the desired file.  Returns the full path to the file.
'
Public Function GetFileSpec()
    Dim of As OPENFILENAME
    Dim intRet As Integer

                    'set up the file filter and the default type option
    If strNewTypes <> "" Then
        of.lpstrFilter = strNewTypes & strFilter
        of.nFilterIndex = 1
    Else
        of.lpstrFilter = strFilter
        If intDefaultType <> 0 Then
            of.nFilterIndex = intDefaultType
        Else
            of.nFilterIndex = 1
        End If
    End If
                    'define some other dialog options
    of.lpstrTitle = strDialogTitle
    of.lpstrInitialDir = strInitialDir
    of.lpstrFile = strInitialFile & String(512 - Len(strInitialFile), 0)
    of.nMaxFile = 511

                    ' Initialize other parts of the structure
    of.hwndOwner = Application.hWndAccessApp
    of.hInstance = 0
    of.lpstrCustomFilter = 0
    of.nMaxCustrFilter = 0
    of.lpfnHook = 0
    of.lpTemplateName = 0
    of.lCustrData = 0
    of.lpstrFileTitle = String(512, 0)
    of.nMaxFileTitle = 511
    of.lpstrDefExt = vbNullChar
    of.Flags = 0
    of.lStructSize = Len(of)

                    'call the Open dialog routine
    intRet = GetOpenFileName(of)
    If intRet Then
        GetFileSpec = Left(of.lpstrFile, InStr(of.lpstrFile, vbNullChar) - 1)
    Else
        GetFileSpec = ""
    End If

End Function    'End of GetFileSpec
Public Property Let DialogTitle(strTitle As String)
                'store the title for the dialog box
    strDialogTitle = strTitle
End Property

Public Property Let AdditionalTypes(strAddTypes As String)
    Dim Posn As Integer
    Dim i As Integer

                    'don't accept additional types if a default type has been specified
    If intDefaultType <> 0 Then
        MsgBox "You cannot add to the file type filter if a default type is " & _
                "being specified in the DefaultType property.  When the " & _
                "AdditionalTypes property is used, that item " & _
                "is used as the default in the file type filter.", vbCritical, _
                "Browse For File Dialog"
        Exit Property
    End If
                    'check for the "|" delimiter
    Posn = InStr(strAddTypes, "|")
                    'save the new parameter or report an error
    If Posn = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The AdditionalTypes property string does not contain at least " & _
                "one " & Chr$(34) & "|" & Chr$(34) & " character.  " & _
                "You must specify an AdditionalTypes property in the same " & _
                "format that is shown in the " & _
                "following example: " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Chr$(34) & _
                "My Files (*.mf1;*.mf2) | *.mf1;*.mf2 | Your Files (*.yf1;*.yf2) *.yf1;*.yf2" _
                & Chr$(34), vbCritical, "Browse For File Dialog"

        strNewTypes = ""
        Exit Property
    Else
        Do While True
            If InStr(1, strAddTypes, "|") Then
                strNewTypes = strNewTypes & Left$(strAddTypes, _
                    InStr(1, strAddTypes, "|") - 1) & vbNullChar
                strAddTypes = Mid$(strAddTypes, InStr(1, strAddTypes, "|") + 1)
            Else
                strNewTypes = strNewTypes & vbNullChar
                Exit Do
            End If
        Loop
    End If

End Property    'End of AdditionalTypes

Public Property Let DefaultType(strType As String)
    Dim Posn As Integer

    Posn = InStr(strFltrLst, strType)

                'don't accept a default if new types are being specified
    If strNewTypes <> "" Then
        MsgBox "You cannot set the DefaultType property if you are using the " & _
                "AdditionalTypes property to expand the file types filter.  " & _
                "In that case the type specified in the AdditionalTypes property " & _
                "will be the default type.", vbCritical, "Browse For File Dialog"
        Exit Property
                'make sure the selected default actually exists
    ElseIf Posn = 0 Then
        MsgBox "The file type you specified in the DefaultType " & _
                "property is not in the built-in " & _
                "list of file types.  You must either specify one of the " & _
                "built-in file types or use the AdditionalTypes property " & _
                "to specify a complete entry similar to the " & _
                "following example: " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & Chr$(34) & _
                "My Files (*.mf) | *.mf" & Chr$(34), vbCritical, _
                "Browse For File Dialog"
        Exit Property
    Else
                'set up the selected default
        intDefaultType = Trim$(Mid$(strFltrCnt, Posn, 3))
    End If
End Property

Public Property Let InitialFile(strIFile As String)
    strInitialFile = strIFile

End Property

Public Property Let InitialDir(strIDir As String)
    strInitialDir = strIDir

End Property

'   This routine initializes the string constants that are used by this class
'
Private Sub Class_Initialize()
                        'define some initial conditions
    strDialogTitle = "Browse For a File"
    strInitialDir = ""
    strInitialFile = ""
    strNewTypes = ""
                        'define the filter string and the look-up strings
    strFilter = "All Files (*.*)" & vbNullChar & "*.*" & vbNullChar & _
                "Text Files (*.txt;*.prn;*.csv)" & vbNullChar & "*.txt;*.prn;*.csv" & vbNullChar & _
                "Word Documents (*.doc)" & vbNullChar & "*.doc" & vbNullChar & _
                "Word Templates (*.dot)" & vbNullChar & "*.dot" & vbNullChar & _
                "Rich Text Files (*.rtf)" & vbNullChar & "*.rtf" & vbNullChar & _
                "Excel Files (*.xls)" & vbNullChar & "*.xls" & vbNullChar & _
                "Databases (*.mdb;*.accdb)" & vbNullChar & "*.mdb;*.accdb" & vbNullChar & _
                "Personal Document Format (*.pdf)" & vbNullChar & "*.pdf" & vbNullChar & _
                "HTML Documents (*.html;*.htm)" & vbNullChar & "*.html;*.htm" & vbNullChar

    strFltrLst = "*.* *.txt *.prn *.csv *.doc *.dot *.rtf *.xls *.mdb *.accdb  *.pdf *.html *.htm"
    strFltrCnt = "  1   2     2     2     3     4     5     6     7     7        8     9      9"

End Sub
```

***And here is the second module, `modBackup` -***

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Declare Function CopyFile& Lib "kernel32" Alias "CopyFileA" (ByVal _
lpExistingFilename As String, ByVal lbNewFileName As String, ByVal _
bFailIfExists As Long)

Public AllowClose As Boolean
Public Sub MakeFileCopy(strExistingFile As String, _
                   strNewfile As String, _
                   blnDoNotOverWrite As Boolean, _
                   Optional blnShowMessage As Boolean = False)


   Dim strMessage As String

   strExistingFile = strExistingFile
   strNewfile = strNewfile

   If CopyFile(strExistingFile, strNewfile, blnDoNotOverWrite) = 1 Then
       strMessage = "File successfully copied."
   Else
       strMessage = "File copy failed."
   End If

   If blnShowMessage Then
       MsgBox strMessage, vbInformation, "Copy File"
   End If

End Sub

Public Function BackUp(strBackEnd As String, strBackUp As String) As Boolean

   Const FILEINUSE = 3356
   Dim dbs As DAO.Database
   Dim strMessage As String
   Dim strBackUpTemp As String

   ' if back up file exists get user confirmation
   ' to delete it
   If Dir(strBackUp) <> "" Then
       strMessage = "Delete existing file " & strBackUp & "?"
       If MsgBox(strMessage, vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Confirm") = vbNo Then
           strMessage = "Back up aborted."
           MsgBox strMessage, vbInformation, "Back up"
           Exit Function
       Else
           ' make temporary copy of backend file and then delete it
           strBackUpTemp = Left(strBackUp, InStr(strBackUp, ".")) & "bak"
           MakeFileCopy strBackUp, strBackUpTemp, False
           Kill strBackUp
       End If
   End If

   On Error Resume Next
   ' attempt to open backend exclusively
   Set dbs = OpenDatabase(Name:=strBackEnd, Options:=True)

   Select Case Err.Number
       Case 0
       ' no error so proceed
       dbs.Close
       Application.CompactRepair strBackEnd, strBackUp
       If Err.Number = FILEINUSE Then
           ' file in use by current user
           strMessage = "The file " & strBackEnd & _
               " is currently unavailable. " & _
               " You may have a table in it open."
           MsgBox strMessage
           ' rename temporary copy of back up file
           ' if exists, back to original
           If Dir(strBackUpTemp) <> "" Then
               MakeFileCopy strBackUpTemp, strBackUp, False
               Kill strBackUpTemp
           End If
           Exit Function
       Else
           On Error GoTo 0
           ' ensure back up file created
           If Dir(strBackUp) = Mid(strBackUp, InStrRev(strBackUp, "\") + 1) Then
               strMessage = "Back up successfully carried out."
               BackUp = True
               ' delete temporary copy of back up file if exists
               On Error Resume Next
               Kill strBackUpTemp
               On Error GoTo 0
           Else
               strMessage = "Back up failed."
               ' rename temporary copy of back up file
               ' if exists, back to original
               If Dir(strBackUpTemp) <> "" Then
                   MakeFileCopy strBackUpTemp, strBackUp, False
                   Kill strBackUpTemp
               End If
           End If
           MsgBox strMessage, vbInformation, "Back up"
       End If
       Case FILEINUSE
       ' file in use - inform user
       strMessage = "The file " & strBackEnd & _
           " is currently unavailable. " & _
           " It may be in use by another user."
       MsgBox strMessage
       ' rename temporary copy of back up file,
       ' if exists, back to original
       If Dir(strBackUpTemp) <> "" Then
           MakeFileCopy strBackUpTemp, strBackUp, False
           Kill strBackUpTemp
       End If
       Case Else
       ' unknown error - inform user
       MsgBox Err.Description, vbExclamation, "Error"
       ' rename temporary copy of back up file
       ' if exists, back to original
       If Dir(strBackUpTemp) <> "" Then
           MakeFileCopy strBackUpTemp, strBackUp, False
           Kill strBackUpTemp
       End If
   End Select

End Function


Public Function GetBackEndPath() As Variant

    GetBackEndPath = DLookup("BackEndPath", "FileLocations")

End Function
Public Function GetBackUpPath() As Variant

    GetBackUpPath = DLookup("BackUpPath", "FileLocations")

End Function
```

I am 100% uncertain which errors the `CheckLinks` sub-routine is supposed to be looking for.  I tried to find some information regarding the different errors, such as `3024` and `3044` but they didn't provide me any useful information as to how exactly these error codes associate with this routine.

The wacky part is the original "template" database works perfectly in all aspects.  I copy/pasted over all the modules, routines, forms, etc. and made them my "own" to match up with the host database styles and themes, and now they don't work.  What the heck am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you step-debugged?

Comment: Yeah, used myself some F8 stepping and no errors, however it never makes it to "```Form_Open()```".  It simply says the back-end is not found and the only option is to stop all macros.  When putting a stop point on ```Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)``` it never actually makes it that far.  Should I put this code under ```Form_Load()```?  I have other code located under that sub already.

Comment: Tried placing the doe under ```Form_Load()``` and same thing happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out what the problem was.  The initial form must not be bound to any data.  It needs to not rely on the backend in order to load "*to the point*" of executing the subroutines which check for the proper back-end files.